# Values emitted by RxJS Subject not going through .pipe(...)

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In the code below I tried to build an RxJS pipe and process values emitted by a subject using `pipe`. The code works but the result is different from what I expected to get.

```
const rxjs = require("rxjs");
var subject = new rxjs.Subject();

subject
.pipe(rxjs.tap(console.log('tap')))
.subscribe(console.log);

function sendRequest(requestID, cb) {
  var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 3 + 1)) + 5;
  var request = {
    hostname: "httpbin.org",
    headers: { "request-id": requestID },
    path: "/delay/." + delay,
  };
  require("http")
    .get(request, (res) => {
      var body = "";
      res.on("data", function (chunk) { body += chunk; });
      res.on("end", function () { cb(res, body); });
    })
    .end();
}

concurrentRequests(5);
function concurrentRequests(limit) {
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    sendRequest(i, function (res, body) {
      var reqID = JSON.parse(body).headers["Request-Id"];
      subject.next("Concurrent Response #" + reqID + " returned a " + res.statusCode);
    });
  }
}
```

My purpose is to build a pipe to process each emitted value using `Subject` from the RxJS library and when I ran the code above I expected to get this output:

```
tap
Concurrent Response #1 returned a 200
tap
Concurrent Response #0 returned a 200
tap
Concurrent Response #2 returned a 200
tap
Concurrent Response #3 returned a 200
tap
Concurrent Response #4 returned a 200
```

But the output was:

```
tap
Concurrent Response #1 returned a 200
Concurrent Response #0 returned a 200
Concurrent Response #2 returned a 200
Concurrent Response #3 returned a 200
Concurrent Response #4 returned a 200
```

Why are the emitted values are not going through the pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```js
subject.pipe(rxjs.tap(console.log('tap')))
```

you provided a value instead of a callback:

```js
subject.pipe(rxjs.tap(() => console.log('tap')))
```

You executed `console.log('tab')` and passed `undefined` value to `rxjs.tap`, while in fact you want to add an **observer**.